# Ktor Client Apache: Content-Length not added automatically

Tags: web-scraping, content-length, ktor-client

I'm trying to scrape a page that is super picky and will fail if I don't add the content-length.

The requests made by ktor client (with apache engine) won't include the Content-Length header, why?

And how do I make it appear?